# What did the "gear warning horn" on the North American P-51 sound like?

Tags: aviation-history, landing-gear, p-51, cockpit-alerts

I'm working on a sound project for a P51 simulation and I'm having real trouble trying to find a reference on how the P51 gear warning horn sounded like. What mechanisms were used in the '40s to make these kind of sounds?

Comment: I don’t even know if the airplane had a gear warning horn on it.

Comment: The tail warning radar just used a mini dingalingaling fire bell along with a red light on the glareshield.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Interesting question.  Unfortunately, I couldn't locate the part in the [P-51D/K parts catalog](http://www.avialogs.com/index.php/en/aircraft/usa/northamericanaviation/p-51mustang/an-01-60je-4-parts-catalog-p-51d-and-p-51k-aircraft.html#download), but, if an [E-bay seller](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Type-E-2-Landing-Gear-Warning-Horn-WWII-Aircraft-P51-B25-P38-P40-P47-Warbirds-/252619301037) is to be believed, it had an E-2 Faraday horn, which appears to be an electrically actuated alarm.  Faraday is (was) the name of an alarm manufacturer most commonly known for their fire alarms.  Based on a history paraphrased from [cteksys.net](http://fire.cteksys.net/frd-antique.html) (emphasis is mine), this seems to be plausible:

> Faraday, was founded in 1875 and is now one of the leading
> manufacturers of Notification Appliances, Fire Alarm Control Panels,
> and Clock Systems in the United States.  (Statement in 2002) ...
>
> ... In the 1940s Documents have been located with the name Schwarze-Faraday at 130 Church Street Adrian Michigan showing the
> company pressing into signaling equipment for industrial applications
> including factories , ships, and **airplanes**.

It's not the original, but a circa-1960s Sperti-Faraday horn (the company name from 1937-1965) sounds like this:

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed reply! <3. Yesterday after I asked this I continued investigating and the closest I got was this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Type-E-2-Landing-Gear-Warning-Horn-WWII-Aircraft-P51-B25-P38-P40-P47-Warbirds-/252619301037 but it seems to be made by Sparks Withington Co. According to the seller they "fit the following aircraft..." in which the P51 is included, but maybe it wasn't on the original equipment. Your reference is the closest I got so far. Many thanks again.